# What is the correct Resource.Load path?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, texture2d

I'm trying to load a `Texture2D` (.png) resource using [`Resource.Load`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Resources.Load.html). I've tried following path patterns:

```
Assets/CaseSensitivePath/TextureName
CaseSensitivePath/TextureName
Assets/CaseSensitivePath/TextureName.png
CaseSensitivePath/TextureName.png
```

Every time, `Resource.Load(path, typeof(Texture2D))` returns null. This is my code and error handling:

```
public class LazyResource<T> where T : UnityEngine.Object
{

    //Path is read-only
    public string path { get { return _path; } }
    private string _path = "";
    //Whether NOT FOUND warning was thrown
    //in that case, further load attemts are ommited and the resource returns always null...
    public bool failed = false;
    //Constructor uses the path as first parameter
    public LazyResource(string path) {
        _path = path;
    }
    //Cached resource
    private T cache = null;

    public T res
    {
        get
        {
            //Does not re-try if it failed before
            if (cache == null && !failed)
            {
                //Load the proper type of resource
                cache = (T)Resources.Load(_path, typeof(T));
                //Throw warning (once)
                if (cache == null)
                {
                    Debug.LogWarning("Icon not found at '" + _path + "'!");
                    failed = true;
                }
            }
            //Can return null
            return cache;
        }
    }
}
```

Error:

```
Icon not found at 'Textures/GUI/Build/egg'!
UnityEngine.Debug:LogWarning(Object)
LazyResource`1:get_res() (at Assets/WorldObject/LazyResource.cs:28)
Actions.Action:GetMenuIcon() (at Assets/WorldObject/Action.cs:203)
HUD:DrawActions(Action[]) (at Assets/Player/HUD/HUD.cs:115)
HUD:DrawOrdersBar() (at Assets/Player/HUD/HUD.cs:85)
HUD:OnGUI() (at Assets/Player/HUD/HUD.cs:63)
```

What is the correct path to load a texture in the Unity3D project?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create a Resources folder in your Assets folder:

[image: Resources folder example]

Then use [`Resources.Load()`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Resources.Load.html):

```
Resources.Load<Texture2D>("MyFolder/MyTexture");
```

---

Comment: It's in `Assets/GUI/Build/egg.png`. The problem is that I didn't know you must use [the Resources folder](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/14748/c-resourcesload-problem.html)... That sucks. I want to organize my files as I will.

Comment: If you want to use `Resources.Load` then you need to put the resource in the **Resource folder**.

Comment: I'll use something different.

Comment: For me @apxcode solved it... I really just felt Assets folder is for this, my intuition was `Resources.Load` was all about loading from assets. But no: you have to make a resources folder by hand. Strange lesson to learn.